# why is my focus pseudo class not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

I am making a search bar in my page header using a form element container with input and a button inside it. I am making the form changes color when hover over it and when you click it.

somehow the focus pseudo-class isn't working even though I put :active pseudo-class within the same selector block.

snippets:

```css
/* general css */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "calibri";
}

.header h2 {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: azure;
    
}

.header h2 a {
    color: azure;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header h2 a:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 24, 81);
}

.sponsers img, .social-media img {
    width: 40px;
}

.sponsers img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.nav-menu ul{
    margin: 10px;
} 

/*general css end*/

.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    background-image: url("/Images/blogimage.jfif");
    background-blend-mode:multiply;
    background-size:cover;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    } 

.header h1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    margin: 2em;
    color: aliceblue;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: initial;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

.nav-menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, .3);
    color: rgb(255, 24, 81);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.search-bar {
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(236, 220, 220, 0.817);
    align-items: center;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search-bar input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
    color: black;
    border-radius: inherit;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: o;
    color: inherit;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.search-bar:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 24, 81, .6);
}

.search-bar:active, .search-bar:focus {
    background-color: rgba(134, 131, 181, 0.3);

}

.search-bar:hover::placeholder {
    color: rgba(236, 220, 220, 0.817);
}

.search-bar:focus::placeholder {
    color: rgba(67, 60, 60, 0.6);
}

.search-bar button {
    border-radius: inherit;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search-bar img {
    size: 30px;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
}
```

```html
    <header class="main-container header">
        <h2 class="header-element main-header"><a href="index.html">blog name</a></h2>
        <nav class="header-element nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <form class="header-element search-bar" action="">
            <input type="search" placeholder="search the blog">
            <button type="submit">
                <img src="/images/loupe.png" alt="search-image">
            </button>
        </form>
        <h1 class="header-element title">Read fresh fake test blog insights in this fake test blog site which is fake and is just a fake test</h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: how do you expect `:focused` or `:active` to behave? a form is not focused at all, an input is. or a select. or even a button. but never a form. see the `:has` pseudoclass, it may help you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the **input** inside the form after that you will get your expected result. Here is the solution

```
.search-bar input:hover::placeholder {
     color: rgba(236, 220, 220, 0.817);
}

.search-bar input:focus::placeholder {
     color: rgba(67, 60, 60, 0.6);
}
```